# List all devices my app is installed and have a specific System Feature

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-play-console

I've been searching, with no luck, for a way to list all the **devices my app is installed and have a specific *System Feature***. For example if you head over to `Play Console > Reach and devices > Device catalog > Add filter` and add a *System Feature*, it will list all the supported devices (check attached screenshot).

However, I want to get a detailed list of the **devices my app is installed and that possess this feature**.

Are you guys aware of a way to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `google-analytics` I assume that you're trying to filter the event data in Google Analytics based on the device that reported those events.

No such filtering on device capabilities is available in Google Analytics that I know of. You'll have to make your own mapping from the capabilities you want to filter on to a list of device types, and then filter on those device types in Google Analyics.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for such a quick reply. I started looking in Firebase Analytics and then activated the Google Analytics 4 integration for my project, but couldn't find sth there either.

Do you know if by exporting the data from GA4 to BigQuery I'd be able to perform such a query (have little experience with BigQuery so not sure what I should search for).

Comment: Exporting to BigQuery gives you a subset of the data that you can find in the Google Analytics console. So if something isn't available in the GA dashboard, it definitely won't be in the export either.